# iOS assigning 192.168.3.0/8 to an IPSec network interface - bug in iOS?

Tags: ios, vpn

We have managed to establish a VPN from an iPhone to a Lancom 1793VA. The VPN is based on IPSec, IKEv2 and machine certificates. When the iPhone establishes the VPN, the VPN gateway assigns it an IP address, a subnet and the DNS server via IKE-CFG.

Actually, this is all working well; the iPhone can access internal resources behind the VPN gateway as desired. However, there is one problem left:

We wanted to have a look behind the scenes with the VPN turned on, downloaded [System Guard](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/system-guard/id734858363?ls=1) and with its help found that iOS had created a new network interface `ipsec2` and had assigned the subnet `192.168.3.0/8` to it. This is all correct except for the fact that per [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) there is no such private subnet. Only a part of the `192.` address range is private; that is, the part `192.168.0.0/16`.

We are quite sure that the VPN gateway handles IKE-CFG correctly (iPhones are the only devices with that problem we encountered so far (we didn't test MacOS yet)). Even if the VPN gateway would behave erroneously, iOS wouldn't use subnets which (per the RFC mentioned above) can't exist, would it?

Could somebody please explain what is going here and how to make iOS behave correctly? The current behavior is very problematic because the affected devices will be unable to access *public* IP addresses of the form `192.n.o.p` where `n` is any number between `1` and `254` except `168`.

Comment: The next question would logically be "what is the iPhone *doing* with that interface?" Not being a network guy I can only guess but perhaps that interface is used by iOS for strictly internal use? Or some other need that Apple decided on? Is it communicating over the VPN using that IP?

Comment: The iPhone seems to do with that interface what would we expect from it: Send traffic to and get traffic via VPN / IPSec. The VPN itself works like a charm. The problem is the network mask of the VPN / IPSec network interface. For example, `192.169.1.1` clearly is a public IP address which could be assigned to (let's say) a bank in the public internet. Now, due to the wrong netmask, the iPhone cannot connect to that bank's website any more as long as the VPN is established.

Comment: Very strange, you might need a network analyzer like WireShark to see exactly what it is trying to do, which is way beyond my expertise, but might give you some clues as to what is going on.